# Flexbuilder 3 Install under Linux

Tags: linux, apache-flex, flex3, flexbuilder

Solving this problem would make my life a hundredfold easier, because working in Windows XP blows, and save for this one Adobe POS, I would be working entirely in Linux.

The Flex project I'm trying to build can be built successfully on Flexbuilder 3 Pro (licensed version, 3.2 SDK) in both Windows XP and Mac OS X.

I followed [these instructions](http://blog.danyul.id.au/?p=68) to get a basic install of Flexbuilder under Fedora 13 (32-bit machine, so I skipped the instructions for 64-bit) - deviating only to install Flexbuilder under `/opt/flexbuilder`.  I tried several different versions of the SDK to work with this particular project, and had best success with SDK 3.4.0, which is currently in my `/opt/flexbuilder/sdks` directory.  After a few dead ends, I also skipped the step where the Air SDK overwrites the Flex SDK (it only adds a couple of Air-specific binaries).

I ran into the "An internal build error problem has occured" after attempting a build.  I followed [these instructions](http://insideria.com/2009/09/fixed-an-internal-build-error.html) to patch the `zornproject.jar` file successfully, and was able to get rid of the error.

And here's where I end up in uncharted territory.

When I build the project, I was unable to locate a reference to a library that was needed by the project.  This library is `datavisualization.swc`.  I took my co-workers version of his Flex SDK `frameworks` directory, which contains the licensed libraries.  After making a backup and replacing my SDK `frameworks` directory with his, I attempted to build again, but it still fails to locate the classes in the `datavisualization.swc` library.

If anyone has been successfully with getting the licensed Flexbuilder 3 installed/configured/blessed correctly under Linux, please enlighten me to your wise steps - because working in Windows XP has been nothing but a huge PITA.

Answer (score 1):

Hey there, I feel your pain.  I also use Flex Builder under Linux (support from Adobe is a joke).

I am at home right now and don't have my work laptop with me... so I cannot verify that what I am about to say is completely correct.

At any rate.... you need to have the `datavisualization.swc` library in your `frameworks` directory - so you are on the right track.  However you also need to have the `datavisualization-xx.swc` (not 100% sure of the name of this library) library in your local/frameworks directory - and this is the part that I'm not sure of.  I'll double check the directory / library tomorrow when I am in front of my work laptop.

**EDIT**

Alright, below see the structure of the SDK I am currently building against:

```
sdks/3.4.0/frameworks/libs
├── air
│   ├── airframework.swc
│   ├── airglobal.swc
│   ├── AIRIntrospector.js
│   ├── AIRLocalizer.js
│   ├── AIRMenuBuilder.js
│   ├── AIRSourceViewer.js
│   ├── applicationupdater.swc
│   ├── applicationupdater.swf
│   ├── applicationupdater_ui.swc
│   ├── applicationupdater_ui.swf
│   └── servicemonitor.swc
├── datavisualization.swc
├── flex.swc
├── framework.swc
├── player
│   ├── 10
│   │   └── playerglobal.swc
│   └── 9
│       └── playerglobal.swc
├── rpc.swc
└── utilities.swc

4 directories, 18 files

sdks/3.4.0/frameworks/locale
├── en_US
│   ├── airframework_rb.swc
│   ├── datavisualization_rb.swc
│   ├── framework_rb.swc
│   └── rpc_rb.swc
└── ja_JP
    ├── airframework_rb.swc
    ├── datavisualization_rb.swc
    ├── framework_rb.swc
    └── rpc_rb.swc

2 directories, 8 files
```

Lastly, I would make sure the folder permissions are correct: logged in user needs `rx` permissions on the SDK directory.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend using [IntelliJ](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) for doing Flex development on Linux.  I've made the switch and am much more productive now.  :)

Comment: No.  Only the enterprise edition.  But they give away enterprise edition licenses all the time.  JUGs, open source projects, etc.